# Как правильно в письменной речи: коррозионностойкая или коррозионно-стойкая (сталь)?

Tags: орфография

В ГОСТах стоит "коррозионно-стойкая", а в самых разных изданиях "коррозионностойкая".

Answer (score 3):

В разных изданиях встречаются две формы письма: ***коррозионностойкая и коррозионно-стойкая***.

Почему? Дело в том, что термин со слитным написанием раньше использовался в стандарте https://lador.ru/gost/gost-5632-72.pdf

В новом стандарте слово имеет дефисное написание http://docs.cntd.ru/document/1200113778

Это же написание фиксируют современные орфографические словари, поэтому писать надо именно так: ***коррозионно-стойкая.***

2) С другой стороны, хочется написать это слово **слитно**, и это вполне объяснимо, так как соответствует **общим правилам**.

Сталь стойкая по отношению к коррозии, способ образования — чистое сложение (*коррозионно + стойкий*).  Дефисное же написание имеют сложные прилагательные, составленные из основ прилагательных, то есть ***коррозионная стойкая сталь,*** но это же не наш случай.

3) **Но все правила имеют ограничения**, и это в первую очередь касается **специальных терминов**.

Дефисная форма более **удобна для понимания** "длинного" слова, но главное, существует ряд сходных терминов: ***коррозионно-агрессивный, коррозионно-устойчивый.*** Эти слова уж точно удобнее писать через дефис, так как вторая часть начинается **на гласную.** И конечно же, желательно, чтобы эти термины писались **одинаково.**

Так можно объяснить дефисное написание слова ***коррозионно-стойкий.***

Comment: _Sharon: Сталь стойкая по отношению к коррозии, способ образования — чистое сложение (**коррозионно** + стойкий). **Дефисное же написание имеют сложные прилагательные, составленные из основ прилагательных**, то есть коррозионная стойкая сталь, но это же не наш случай._ === А что такое, по-вашему, "коррозионно"? Наречия такого не существует, есть только прилагательное "коррозионный" с основой "коррозионн".  Итого имеем: **коррозионн**ый + стойкий. А далее — см. Ваше: _Дефисное же написание имеют сложные прилагательные, составленные из основ прилагательных._

Comment: А зачем Вам наречие? При чистом сложении берется опорное прилагательное "стойкий" и к нему добавляется основа прилагательного "коррозионн-" и соединительная гласная О. В Грамматике-80 этот способ назван чистым сложением, в качестве первой основы могут использоваться основы различных частей речи, в том числе прилагательных.  Если между основами подчинительная связь, то написание слитное: горноспасательный, старомосковский.

Answer (score 2):

> Как правильно в письменной речи: коррозионностойкая или
>   коррозионно-стойкая (сталь)?

Правильно — с дефисом: ***коррозионно-стойкая***.

См. [**словари на Грамоте.ру.**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE*&all=x)

Answer (score 2):

Единственный общеязыковый словарь, который включает это слово - орфографический Лопатина. Там оно в дефисном написании. 
В специальных словарях наблюдается колебание.

Но коли уж ГОСТ принял рекомендацию Лопатина, придется согласиться.

Честно говоря, больше напоминает узаконенное отступление от правила, чем мотивированное исключение. В массе своей подобные слова по современным правилам пишутся слитно. Хотя возможно, что тут возобладала как раз давняя традиция - середины прошлого века. Технические термины весьма инертны, их написание часто отстаёт от актуальных правил.

Comment: А как быть со словами: электропроводность, теплоизоляция, ударопрочность и т. п ?

Comment: @Игорь Ну их-то, слава богу, никто ж не пишет через дефис. Или я что-то пропустил? Но вообще-то с каждым **исключением** надо разбираться отдельно. А когда все по общему правилу - то какие вопросы?

Answer (score 0):

Если всё, относящееся к техническим терминам, писать через дефис, то тогда будет:
тепло-ёмкость, электро-проводность, грузо-подъёмкость и т.д.?
Может быть редакторам ГОСТов поработать над корректировкой содержания с учётом современных достижений, требований экологической, пожарной, сантехнической и других безопасностей, а, заодно, орфографии для унификации требований в этой области?